# Changing an array class to hold a dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic-arrays

everything i have read says this should be easy and that you just add these three lines

```
typedef double* DoublePtr;
  DoublePtr p;
  p = new double [10]
```

but where do i add this code? Everything i have tried just breaks my program what am I missing? I tried a set function to set the value of max size but it didn't work either
does anyone know how to do this?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
const int MAX_SIZE = 50;

class ListDynamic
{

    public:

        ListDynamic();
        bool full();
        int getSize();
        void addValue(double value);
        double getValue(int index);
        double getLast();
        void deleteLast();
        friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const ListDynamic& thisList);  

    private:
        double listValues[MAX_SIZE];
        int size;
};
int main()
{
    double value;
    ListDynamic l;
    cout << "size of List " << l.getSize() << endl;



    cout << "New size of List " << l.getSize() << endl;
    cout << "First Value: " << l.getValue(0) << endl;
    cout << "Last Value: " << l.getLast() << endl;
    cout << "deleting last value from list" << endl;
    l.deleteLast();
    cout << "new list size "  << l.getSize() << endl;
    cout << "the list now contains: " << endl << l << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

ListDynamic::ListDynamic()
{
    size = 0;
}

bool ListDynamic::full()
{
    return (size == MAX_SIZE);
}

int ListDynamic::getSize()
{
    return size;
}

void ListDynamic::addValue(double value)
{
    if (size < MAX_SIZE)
    {
        listValues[size] = value;
        size++;
    }
    else
        cout << "\n\n*** Error in ListDynamic Class: Attempting to add value past max limit.";
}

double ListDynamic::getValue(int index)
{
    if (index < size)
        return listValues[index];
    else
        cout << "\n\n*** Error in ListDynamic Class: Attempting to retrieve value past current size.";
}
double ListDynamic::getLast()
{
    if (size > 0)
        return getValue(size - 1);
    else
        cout << "\n\n*** Error in ListDynamic Class: Call to getLast in Empty List.";
}

void ListDynamic::deleteLast()
{
    if (size > 0)
        size--;
    else
        cout << "\n\n*** Error in ListDynamic Class: Call to deleteLast in Empty List.";
}
ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const ListDynamic& thisList)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < thisList.size; i++)
        out << thisList.listValues[i] << endl;
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using `std::vector` again?

Comment: Are you forced to use a dynamic array? In C++ you have plenty of ready to use things from STL like `std::vector` or `std::list`.

Comment: how is your program  'breaking'? what are you expecting?

Comment: for this one I am not supposed to use vectors. I am supposed to make this class that i was given hold a dynamic array. I am having problems with the private variable MAX_SIZE when I try to make the array dynamic I think Im not changing or adding the right code.

Comment: If you want to close `std::vector`, you can't do it with just C-arrays. You need to use the `std::allocator` class template or similar in order to do resizing of the vector. Or, if you still want to use an array, you should have a constructor in which you pass in an integer, and in the initializer list of the constructor you should dynamically allocate the array.

Comment: dynamically allocate the array is exactly what I am trying to do but dont know where to start my lame text book says its easy and i just have to add the three lines of code at the top.

Comment: Well, your identification of the quality of the textbook certainly tells a story. Adding just those three lines isn't much, to be sure. All they do is dyna-allocate a fixed block 10-elements wide. If this is the textbook's idea of teaching dynamic memory management there are better examples, of that I'm sure we agree.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `listValues` to a `double*`

```
double* listValues;
```

And when you add a value greater than the size, you'll need to reallocate the array your array and copy the elements of the former array to the new one. For example:

```
void ListDynamic::addValue(double value)
{
    if (full())
    {
        double* temp = new double[size];
        std::copy(listValues, listValues + size, temp);

        delete[] listValues;
        listValues = new double[size + 1];

        std::copy(temp, temp + size, listValues);
        listValues[size] = value;
        delete[] temp;
    } else
    {
        listValues[size++] = value;
    }
}
```